# Excel nested If and VLOOKUP statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

I would like help with making a function to do the following: if the information in a cell is equal to information stored in a list (in another worksheet but in the same workbook) than add that cell + another cell, if false than display FALSE or something else.

I'm new to Excel but a decade ago did a course on visual basic and remember the basic principles of some of these functions. I tried a number of different ways but have not come up with something that works. I've tried nesting `VLOOKUP` within `IF` statements as well as `HLOOKUP` and `LOOKUP` but had no success.

- `RolledSteel` is my product list.
- `List` is my worksheet that contains `RolledSteel` (plus other lists).
- `Invoice` is the worksheet that contains the functions that would link to `RolledSteel` or `List`.

Functions I have tried but had no success with:

```
=IF(N10=List!$A$2:$G$13,W10+W10,FALSE)

=IF(N10=RolledSteel,W10+W10,FALSE)

=IF(N10=VLOOKUP(N10,RolledSteel,4,FALSE),W10+W10,FALSE)
```

I have a few more questions ahead but for now I would like to resolve this issue. Any help would be so very greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thining the easiest way to do this would be using the [Match()](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/MATCH-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function together with `If(Isnumber()` as follows:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(N10,RolledSteel,FALSE)),W10+W10,"FALSE")
```

Basically, you're saying:

- Look for `N10` in the `RolledSteel` list
- If it's there, you'll get a number back, so `ISNUMBER` will be true, so do the sum
- If it's not, you'll get an error, so `ISNUMBER` will be false, so return "FALSE"

Hope that makes sense and does the trick

Answer (score 0):

Try the `Countif()` function. For example, `=COUNTIF(List,N10)` returns the number of occurrences of the value of N10 in the List. You can expand on that to:

`=IF(
    COUNTIF(List,N10)>0
    ,W10+W10
    ,FALSE
    )`